# How do transporters re materialize the energy/matter stream into the subject?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-transporter

So they have a big stream of sub atomic particles, how do they actually bring it altogether perfectly? I mean their is zillions of particles, what do they use to put all the particles into atoms, then molecules, and so on into the perfect form of the subject?

Comment: I don't think it was ever explained in that detail. But you could also ask: How does your screen manage to get all the pixels right. There are millions of them and they all can assume over 16 million different colours. Short answer; Sophisticated technology.

Comment: Maybe they have calculated that some of those instable sub-atomic particles would trigger a reaction at certain time slices so there is possibility that some reactions will happen at delta-T time after the beam start. delta-T means a delta-R too. Quantum computing can achieve that zillions of particle position computations. They have strong computer. Also there is uncertainity which can cause the subject to have wrong cells in wrong places.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a in-universe answer or a real-universe answer?
If you seek for the last one:

We all know that many parts of Star Trek are imaginable in todays physics. This may be Impulse drive, phasers, warp drive or leaps of time. But Beaming, unfortunatelly, is fantasy.
Gene Roddenberry once stated for TOS that Beaming has been "invented" for two reasons:

- You don't want to see shuttles starting, flying and landing instead of one Beaming action every episode.
- Creating a shuttle scene every time instead of beaming simply has been to expensive back in those days.

Sorry, if youre looking for a in-universe answer, because I cant answer that. Maybe it is stated in the Technical Manual, which I didn't read yet.

Comment: A little clarification on the shuttles.  The costs of the shuttle props prevented them from being built initially.  It wasn't until model company AMT offered to build the initial shuttle prop for free in exchange for marketing rights that it even happened.  But by then they were already well into filming the first season.  The transporters were created because the shuttle sets and props weren't ready in time.

Answer (score 1):

In-universe, the [transporter](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transporter)'s functions are quite well described.

The subject is scanned, dematerialised, converted into a stream of matter and then   "**transported**" to the remote destination along an '*annular confinement beam*'. At the destination end, this beam then creates a 'matrix' which the particles fill, a bit like pouring water into a jug.

This excerpt from the "[TNG Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual)" gives a little more info;

[image: Transporter]

[image: Transporter Function]